# EditorFor + TModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, razor, editorfor

the signature for this very useful method states I can indicate a type:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
)
```

... the docs very understandably state that TModel is *"The type of model"*.  It must be my particular bent that this description conveys no meaning to me whatsoever.  I've googled for an explanation but found zilch.

I'm in a view where `@model Website.Models.Product` but want to create an editor for something of a different type.  I thought I could:

```
@Html.EditorFor(@ViewBag.AClassOfTheOtherType)
```

or maybe (I'm obviously guessing):

```
@Html.EditorFor(TheOtherType)
```

but that is not acceptable syntax and so I thought:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x...)
```

but the lambda expression seems to be bound to `@model`... so I thought, "ah!":

```
@Html.EditoFor<TheOtherType>(...)
```

but VS thinks the < starts an HTML tag and indicates the end of my EditorFor call (which fails).

aaaaahhhhh!

how do I do this (in case I actually need to ask)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is (drumroll please)... yes, one can bind the lambda expression with the  type declarator.  the only problem is the Visual Studio editor, which thinks one is ending the C# part and entering the HTML part with the opening < and thus disallows proper code.  Solution:

```
@{ Html.EditoFor<TheOtherType>(...) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested this, but couldn't you do:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => ViewBag.AClassOfTheOtherType)
```

You don't necessarily need to use the variable passed into the Lambda.

Comment: I didn't realise I could do that.  I'll give that a try.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Model - is the Model - the M in MVC

TModel could just as well be sdserweJJG - it's only consistently called TModel out of convention.

Within the helper method for EditorFor you will see something like:

```
 TValue val = expression.Compile()(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
```

this is where the extension method compiles the lambda passed in - for example the `x=>x.Model.Property` part - and gets back the actual Model data to use to build the actual display controls.

The Model is passed to the view when you call `return View(viewModel);` from your controller action.

What you are trying to do doesn't make sense because the method was designed to work with the views Model.

You can however use `@Html.Editor` as this will take the actual value in the way you are trying:

```
@Html.Editor(ViewBag.AClassOfTheOtherType)
```

The sourcecode for MVC is freely available to download and view - it's well worth taking the time to do so :)

Comment: so Model is whatever I bind via the @model directive.  but then, what is the use of .EditorFor<TModel>() if not to specify that the type of the model (to be used in making the call) is something other than Model?

Comment: I tried `@Html.Editor(ViewBag.AClassOfTheOtherType)` but that seems unsupported syntax.  there are 6 overloads and none just take an object like that... aside from that, does .Editor() understand the Shared/EditorTemplates? because I have some stuff encapsulated in there

Comment: what I get:Error 11 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Website.Models.Quiz>' has no applicable method named 'Editor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax. c:\Users\ekkis\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Test\Website\Views\X\Details.cshtml

Comment: any reason this stuff isn't in the TModel?

Comment: I still don't understand this... if the helper provides a means for me to specify the model it should use for the lambda expression, why can't I do `@Html.EditoFor<TheOtherType>(...)`? or, if that is not the intent of the <TModel>, then what is?